# Pre-smoothing point clouds for registration

Tags: image-processing, filtering, smoothing, point-clouds

I collected some depth data that I want to perform registration with indoors. A lot of my registration problems I believe are due to how noisy my input point clouds are, particularly for the likes of walls. I get all these peaks.

Is registration even feasible with this type of data? I have tried bilateral filtering but to smooth these walls I end up smoothing everything else far too much. Unfortunately I cannot get better data than this.

One thing is that I have a good initial alignment as I know approximately where the clouds are in respect to each other and I use PCLs ICP function to finely align the clouds. I just end up with the clouds being out by about 10cm in world coordinates.

Here is an example of the noisy point cloud.

[image: Point cloud example]

Here is also the point cloud data itself: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=86699186324042615889